# What does 'we are bid to' mean?

Tags: ambiguity

<sub>Source: p 116, [*Introducing Philosophy for Canadians: A Text with Integrated Readings*](https://www.amazon.ca/Introducing-Philosophy-Canadians-Integrated-Readings/dp/0195430964) (2011 1 ed) by Solomon, McDermid.
[Primary Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=A3j6XO-G9eoC&lpg=PA110&ots=b6HmKr0TVe&dq=%22so%20we%20are%20bid%20to%20watch%20and%20pray%22%20method%20in%20theology&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q=%22so%20we%20are%20bid%20to%20watch%20and%20pray%22%20method%20in%20theology&f=false) p 110, *Method in Theology, Volume 12* (1972)
by [Bernard J. F. Lonergan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Lonergan)</sub>

> Religious development is not simply the unfolding in all its consequences of a dynamic state of being in love in an unrestricted manner. 
>   For that love is the utmost in self-transcendence, and man's self-transcendence is ever precarious. Of itself, self-transcendence involves ten- 
>   sion between the self as transcending and the self as transcended. So 
>   human authenticity is never Some pure and serene and secure possession. It is ever a withdrawal from unauthenticity, and every successful 
>   withdrawal only brings to light the need for still further withdrawals. 
>   Our advance in understanding is also the elimination of oversights and 
>   misunderstandings. Our advance in truth is also the correction of mistakes and errors. Our moral development is through repentance for 
>   our sins. Genuine religion is and realized by redemption 
>   from the many traps of religious aberration. So **we are bid to** watch 
>   and pray, to make our way in fear and trembling. And it is the greatest 
>   saints that proclaim themselves the greatest sinners, though their sins 
>   seem slight indeed to less holy folk that lack their discernment and 
>   their love  ....

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/18728?rskey=oaDNvW&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) and [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bid) do not list 'bid' as ever being an adjective; so I conjecture 'bid' a deverbal adjective. But from which (of the 2 Semantic Fields of the) verb does this adjective originate?

1. Old English *biddan* "to ask, entreat, beg, pray, beseech; order"
   ⟸ PIE root *g<sup>u̯</sup>hedh-* "to ask, pray"

or 2. Old English *beodan* "offer, proclaim" ⟸ PIE root **bheudh-* "to be aware, make aware"

Comment: Why the -1? You continue to cite the OED, which requires a subscription.

Comment: I'm not sure contextual reasoning is strictly quantifiable, but: of the two meanings of bid you've offered *makes the most sense in context*? For me, one of them isn't applicable *at all*. I still don't know why this seems clear to me (and the two answerers), but eludes you. I think you have some deontological view of usage or something which interferes with your engagement with or comprehension of a text. Or maybe it's the other way round: on first reading, the meaning of the sentence eludes you, so you turn to etymology as an aid, only to find (unsurprisingly!) it unreliable for tht purpose?

Comment: Like Dan, I don't know what steps LeP.. is following when reverse-engineering the  sentence and swapping in an etymological possibility. But to say "We are {proclaimed} to watch and pray" makes no sense to me. But how do I know that? Is it native-speaker's instinct for what is licensed to a given verb? Or is it that I understand the verb **proclaim** to mean "to announce or declare to the public" and thus feel "we are announced to pray" or "we are declared to pray" are a no-go from the get-go? Things are declared or proclaimed to **be** not to **do**.

Comment: @TRomano Better now?

Comment: @DanBron 3. In hindsight, you are correct that I should have been able to reject meaning 2 above as a possibility, but I was incertain because it is semantically, though not idiomatically, possible to say: 'we are declared to {do something}'.

Comment: @DanBron 4. Sorry, what do you mean by `I think you have some deontological view of usage or something which interferes with your engagement with or comprehension of a text.`? I do accept that usage can change.

Comment: @TRomano 5. Please see 3 above. I accept that `"We are {proclaimed} to watch and pray"` is not idiomatic, but it is semantically possible, no?

Comment: @LePressentiment: in my opinion, no, "We are proclaimed to watch and pray" is not possible, syntactically or semantically.  This would not be grammatical: "The king proclaimed us to celebrate the birth of the princess." The king might proclaim June 25 a day of celebration. The king proclaims X **to be** Y.  The king does not proclaim X **to do** Y. Do you understand what I'm getting at there, with **be** and **do**?

Comment: @TRomano Yes, I do `understand what I'm getting at there, with be and do` : you are explaining that the verb 'proclaim' Semantically Selects only 'to be' and NOT 'to do'. I cannot diagnose why, but I failed to discern this Semantic Selection. Maybe I need to read more?

Comment: Perhaps it was the passive, "We are proclaimed..."?  Does the active "The king proclaimed us to celebrate.."  strike your ear as a viable possibility?

Comment: @LePressentiment By *deontological*, I meant you appear to have a philosophical commitment to the idea that there's an explicit and finite set of rules language must adhere to, and numbered among those is the regulation that a word's meaning must be related to its etymology. And so when you encounter a word used apparently as odds with its established etymology,u balk, and try to fit a round peg through a square hole.  Then I speculate this misapprehension is a potential source of your repeated experience in encountering texts whose meaning is obvious on its face to others, but opaque to you.

Comment: I also put forward a related theory, but with cause and effect reversed: that you find a passage confusing, and instead of turning to a dictionary or glossary to dispel your doubts, you turn to an etymology (because again you believe meaning owes some loyalty or duty to meaning), in contravention of the etymological fallacy, falling directly into that hazard and deepening that confusion. But ultimately, I am unable to diagnose the issue you have with interesting texts which most others find straightforward. I don't know if this etymological focus is your disease or ur attempt at a home remedy.

Comment: @TRomano `"The king proclaimed us to celebrate.." strike your ear as a viable possibility?`: Yes, I fear that this does. But I will respect and enact your advice not to use 'proclaim' as such, to be understood.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for your feedback. I think that I did emphasise this truth before in another comment, but I reject that `a word's meaning must be related to its etymology`. It can be sometimes. Perchance we should move this to Chat?

Comment: @DanBron No, I always use both dictionary and etymology, but certainly privilege the dictionary for understanding contemporary usage.

Comment: @LePressentiment Cool, good. I agree we should move to chat. I can't at the moment, but let's not clutter the comments here further. I am sincerely interested in how you approach interpreting texts. The set of questions which occurs to you fascinates me. I'm not sure why, but they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb [bid](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bid) has several meanings and three different passive participles (bidden, bid and bade).

The normal passive participle for the meaning **to ask someone to do something** is **bidden**, however the form used in this sentence, **bid**, is also offered by [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bid)  and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bid).

It could be replaced with the passive participle of **ask**, which is **asked**.

> So we are **asked** to watch and pray....

Comment: **bid** is a variant PP. https://books.google.com/books?id=LTpadDBxTsQC&pg=PA143&dq=%22we+are+bid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw4e_18MLNAhVCOj4KHfz5DhcQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22we%20are%20bid%22&f=false

Comment: @TRomano: Barron's does specifically refer to the meaning related to an auction. I have removed the "possibly incorrect" and added references to other sources that quote this as a valid variant for this meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence

> *to be* bid

has the meaning "to be told what to do", "to be commanded what to" as in

> to do one's [bidding](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bidding)

Comment: "bid" doesn't mean to be told what to do, it means to tell someone what to do. In OP's quote, it's used in passive voice, which of course reverses the sense.

Comment: But that's just what Peter said, "to be told, commanded".

Comment: @ThePhoton: It is confusing because the infinitive is the same as the passive participle. Peter describes the meaning "In your sentence", where it is the passive participle, so his statement is correct.

Comment: I'd say "to be bid" means to be told what to do. Not that "bid" means that itself.